# Examine antiderivates F to f(x)=x, where f is a tangent to F

Tags: integration, derivatives, exponential-function, real-numbers

First of all, sorry for my language as English is not my mother tongue. When it comes to this question I do not find it hard to find the general antiderivate F to f(x)=x as it is x^2/2 + C, where C is a real number. But how do I prove that f is a tangent to F without having any values to work with and input into the functions?

Comment: What do you mean by tangent? Obviously this is not true using the geometric notion of tangency.

Comment: Side note:  your English seems perfect, nothing to apologize for.

Comment: Do you mean slope in tangent?

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is only one value of C for which the parabola is tangent to the line. (C=1/2). So that is the only case you need to deal with.

If $f=ax+b$, the point of tangency requires two equations, namely that the function values match and the slopes match. 
$$ax +b=ax^2/2+bx+c$$
$$a=ax+b$$
Solve to find c again.

Comment: Okay, but how about for example when f(x)=ax+b? Do I only have to find one value of C to prove that f is a tangent to the function F?

Comment: Then again you look for points where the functions are equal and the slopes are. Only 1 value of C for any given a and b. See my edit in the answer.

Comment: @Ollebolle Do you consider this question answered. If yes, please accept an answer. If not, please ask more questions.